# Can't parse date with format in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have values like
`'05272021'` that I need change to date

I tried to use

```
to_date(refund_date::varchar,'MM/dd/yyyy') as refund_date
```

But get:

> "Can't parse '05112021' as date with format 'MM/dd/yyyy'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided format should match source data `05272021`:

```
SELECT try_to_date(refund_date::varchar,'MMddyyyy') as refund_date
...
```

Answer (score 1):

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE_TEST( COL1 VARCHAR);

SELECT * FROM TABLE_TEST;

output:
COL1
20210408

We can use below query if we want to convert string to date format.

SELECT **to_date(col1::varchar,'YYYYMMDD') AS EXPECTED**  FROM TABLE_TEST;

Expected output: 2021-04-08